# PHPBrew update existing install with variant?

Tags: php, phpbrew

Once you've installed a PHP version using `phpbrew install x.x.x`, is it possible to add variants afterwards?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
For example, to install `mb_string()` extenstion use:

```
phpbrew ext install mbstring
```

After installation is completed, don't forget to restart `fpm` with

```
phpbrew fpm restart
```

For more information, look here [here](https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew/wiki/Extension-Installer)